# handling exception for RestAPI unit test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have a method

```
public class ActivityManager {
    private ActivityManager activityManager_;

@Autowired
public ActivityManager(ActivityManager activityManage)
{
    activityManager_= activityManage;
}
@RequestMapping(value ="activityManager/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public List<Data> getData() throws RestControllerException {
        try {
            return activityManage_.fetchData();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RestControllerException();
        }
     }
}
```

And I tried to test the throw exception but it does not work. I got confused into the case what's the status() for resultmatcher should be.

```
    @Test(expected = RestControllerException.class)
        public void getDataError() throws Exception {
           ActivityManager activityManagerMock = Mockito.mock(ActivityManager
                .class); 
doThrow(RestControllerException.class).when(activityManagerMock).fetchData();
            mockMvc_.perform(get("/activityManager")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
        }
```

Is there any document that I can read more about handling exception for restapi unit test?
Thanks

Comment: Where are you setting the mock activityManagerMock to Controller bean.??

Comment: sorry i edited it, activityManage is name of the class

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Autowired
    private ActivityManagerService activityManager;
```

This will inject the actual bean into the controller not the mock which you created.

Add this inside your test class.

```
@Autowired
private ControllerBean controller;

@Before
public void init(){
     ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controller, "activityManager", activityManagerMock);
}
```

This will set the MockObject into activityManager of Controller.
And hence while running test the mock objects fetchData() will be called which inturn throws the exception.